# Docusaurus not setting theme on initial render

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm trying to resolve an issue related with themes on a React website built by Docusaurus.

This problem is most likely related to the fact that `data-theme` attribute for the `html` tag isn't being set on the first render, causing the whole website to appear without a theme for a few seconds (you can set test this by assigning an empty string to `data-theme` property).

Here is a link to the website : https://v2.postgres.ai/

I've tried updating Docusaurus version, but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Experiencing this as well. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @pir looks like the issue was related to something different entirely. For us it was the Cloudflare RocketLoader feature.

Here is my outdated issue on their GiHub repo: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/8379